# Jquery datatable individual searching excluding unsearcable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function EditTemmplate(o) {
        return "<a class='btn btn-primary' href=\"/Customer/Edit/" + o + "\">Edit</a>" + "</li>";
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var table = $('#table').DataTable({
            "dom": 'Bfrtip',
            "order": [2, "asc"],
            "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                if (data.IsActive === false) {
                    $(row).addClass('inactive');
                }
            },
            "serverSide": true,
            "processing": true,
            "paging": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Customer/Get",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataType": "json",
                "complete": function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            },
            "buttons": [
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    text: 'Download Excel',
                    className: "btn",
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [1, 2, 3]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "columns":
                [
                    { data: "ID", title: "", render: EditTemmplate, bSortable: false, searchable: false },
                    { data: "CompanyName", title: "Company Name", "searchable": false },
                    { data: "Contact", title: "Contact Person" },
                    { data: "IDNumber", title: "ID/Reg #" },
                    { data: "EmailAddress", title: "Email" },
                    { data: "ContactNumber", title: "Contact #" }
                ]
        });


        var text = "<tr>";
        $('#table thead th').each(function () {

            var title = $(this).text();
            //Test here if column should be searched
            text += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" /></td>'

        });
        text += "</tr>";
        $("#table thead").append(text);


        // Apply the search
        table.columns().every(function (index) {
            var that = this;

            $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {

                that.search(this.value).draw();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is I do not know how to test if the column is searchable or not, no css class is being added to the column headers, secondly I do not know if I am following the right recipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test non-programmatically by just searching the table for a value which is only in the those first two columns - if it hits, something is wrong!

Within code, you can check the bSearchable property for each column returned by `table.settings()[0].aoColumns`